# Как копировать текст из тега в другой тег и добавить текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как правильно скопировать текстовое содержание тега `<div>` в другой тег `<div>` и добавить тексту.
Нужен код на **jQuery**.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $(".container").text($("#el_1").text(function () {
            let z = "Hello";
            let x = $(".container").text($("#el_1").text())
            return x + z;
            }
        ))
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">кнопка</button>
<p id="el_1">Копируемый текст</p>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let addText = 'Hello'; // текст который мы будем добавлять

$('#button').on('click', function(){ // При нажатии на кнопку..
  let text = $('#el_1').text().trim(); // Получим текст из #el_1 и уберём пробелы на краях текста
  $('.container').text(addText+' '+text); // Вставим текст addText+#el_1 в .container.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">кнопка</button>
<p id="el_1">Копируемый текст</p>
<div class="container"></div>
```